# Only first image loads on javascript

Tags: javascript

I've the following code with which I'm attempting to wait for the load of 3 images before showing a popup that includes them:

```
  function displayBase64Image(base64Image,e,map) {
          var counter=0;
          var length=3;

var imagePlaceholder = document.createElement('image-placeholder')
            var image = document.createElement('img');
            var image2 = document.createElement('img2');
            var image3 = document.createElement('img3');



    image.onload = function() {
          imagePlaceholder.appendChild(image);
          counter++;
          if (counter==length)
          {
            showPopup();
          }
    }

    image2.onload = function() {
        imagePlaceholder.appendChild(image2);
        counter++;
        if (counter==length)
        {
           showPopup()
        }
    }

    image3.onload = function() {
      imagePlaceholder.appendChild(image3);
      counter++;
      if (counter==length)
      {
      showPopup();
      }
    }
imagePlaceholder.innerHTML = '<div id="image-placeholder" ><h3 align="center">Seleccione foto a subir</h3><input type="file" font-family: monospace; id="inputFileToLoad" align="center" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" onclick="fileClicked(event)" onchange="fileChanged(event);setFile(this);" width="48"/><h3 align="center"><button type="button" onclick="checkandpost();">Subir foto</button></h3><h3 align="center">Fotos ya subidas</h3></div><div id="imgTest"></div>';
image.src = base64Image;
image2.src=base64Image
image3.src=base64Image


}
```

But for some reason the only image to ever perform the onLoad is image, image2 and image3 never perform it.

Which could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function displayBase64Image(base64Image,e,map) {
      var counter=0;
      var length=3;

var imagePlaceholder = document.createElement('image-placeholder')
        var image = document.createElement('img');
        var image2 = document.createElement('img');
        var image3 = document.createElement('img');



image.onload = function() {
      imagePlaceholder.appendChild(image);
      counter++;
      if (counter==length)
      {
        showPopup();
      }
}

image2.onload = function() {
    imagePlaceholder.appendChild(image2);
    counter++;
    if (counter==length)
    {
       showPopup()
    }
}

image3.onload = function() {
  imagePlaceholder.appendChild(image3);
  counter++;
  if (counter==length)
  {
  showPopup();
  }
}
imagePlaceholder.innerHTML = '<div id="image-placeholder" ><h3 align="center">Seleccione foto a subir</h3><input type="file" font-family: monospace; id="inputFileToLoad" align="center" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" onclick="fileClicked(event)" onchange="fileChanged(event);setFile(this);" width="48"/><h3 align="center"><button type="button" onclick="checkandpost();">Subir foto</button></h3><h3 align="center">Fotos ya subidas</h3></div><div id="imgTest"></div>';
image.src = base64Image;
image2.src=base64Image
image3.src=base64Image


}
```

The problem is that you want to create `<img2>` and `<img3>` HTML tag. change the to `<img>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.createElement('img2')
```

attempts to create a `<img2>` element, which is not a valid HTML element.

Change your code to

```
var image2 = document.createElement('img');
var image3 = document.createElement('img');
```

On a different note, you should pass the same function to each of your images rathern than writing it all over again. Something along these lines:

```js
function displayBase64Image(base64Image) {
  var counter = 0;
  var length = 3;

  var imagePlaceholder = document.createElement('div');

  imagePlaceholder.innerHTML = '<div id="image-placeholder" ><h3 align="center">Seleccione foto a subir</h3><input type="file" font-family: monospace; id="inputFileToLoad" align="center" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" onclick="fileClicked(event)" onchange="fileChanged(event);setFile(this);" width="48"/><h3 align="center"><button type="button" onclick="checkandpost();">Subir foto</button></h3><h3 align="center">Fotos ya subidas</h3></div><div id="imgTest"></div>';
  var image = document.createElement('img');
  var image2 = document.createElement('img');
  var image3 = document.createElement('img');

  function onLoad(image) {
    imagePlaceholder.appendChild(image);
    counter++;
    if (counter === length) {
      showPopup();
    }
  }

  image.onload = onLoad(image);
  image2.onload = onLoad(image2);
  image3.onload = onLoad(image3);

  image.src = base64Image;
  image2.src = base64Image;
  image3.src = base64Image;
  document.body.appendChild(imagePlaceholder);
}
// defining empty because you haven't included it
function showPopup(){}
displayBase64Image('data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');
```

The code could be further improved, but I have no idea about the context.

A few more considerations: because you're using base64, there's nothing to load. The image is contained in the string.

Which means that `onload` will fire immediately.

Which means by the time you're setting `innerHTML` of your `imagePlaceholder` element, the images are already there and you're replacing them with that string.

So you're effectively deleting the images right away. I have solved this by first assigning the `innerHTML` and then setting the `onload` and `src`s on the images.

Answer (score 1):

just change

```
var image = document.createElement('img');
var image2 = document.createElement('img2');
var image3 = document.createElement('img3');
```

to

```
var image = document.createElement('img');
var image2 = document.createElement('img');
var image3 = document.createElement('img');
```

and final code looks:

```
function displayBase64Image(base64Image,e,map) {
          var counter=0;
          var length=3;

var imagePlaceholder = document.createElement('image-placeholder')
            var image = document.createElement('img');
            var image2 = document.createElement('img');
            var image3 = document.createElement('img');



    image.onload = function() {
          imagePlaceholder.appendChild(image);
          counter++;
          if (counter==length)
          {
            showPopup();
          }
    }

    image2.onload = function() {
        imagePlaceholder.appendChild(image2);
        counter++;
        if (counter==length)
        {
           showPopup()
        }
    }

    image3.onload = function() {
      imagePlaceholder.appendChild(image3);
      counter++;
      if (counter==length)
      {
      showPopup();
      }
    }
imagePlaceholder.innerHTML = '<div id="image-placeholder" ><h3 align="center">Seleccione foto a subir</h3><input type="file" font-family: monospace; id="inputFileToLoad" align="center" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" onclick="fileClicked(event)" onchange="fileChanged(event);setFile(this);" width="48"/><h3 align="center"><button type="button" onclick="checkandpost();">Subir foto</button></h3><h3 align="center">Fotos ya subidas</h3></div><div id="imgTest"></div>';
image.src = base64Image;
image2.src=base64Image
image3.src=base64Image


}
```